# Sorting a vector based on frequency and position of the elements in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a vector and I want to sort it, where the first criterion is frequency. Second criterion is position in the vector. If two elements have the same number of occurrences, I want the most recently seen element to take advantage and go first. In the end, I want to remove duplicate elements from it.

For instance, if the input is this:

```
fn main() {
    let history = vec![3, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 3];
}
```

The output should be:

```
3 4 5 2 6
```

How can I do this in Rust?

Comment: Just to be clear on the algorithm: you want `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` to be sorted as `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`, right?

Comment: @trentcl in case there are no duplicate items, yes. See edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A straightforward method is to build hash maps for frequencies and positions of the elements:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn frequency_map(nums: &[i32]) -> HashMap<i32, usize> {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();

    for &n in nums {
        *map.entry(n).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }
    map
}

fn position_map(nums: &[i32]) -> HashMap<i32, usize> {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();

    for (pos, &n) in nums.iter().enumerate() {
        map.insert(n, pos);
    }
    map
}
```

And then do an unstable sort by position followed by a stable sort by frequency:

```
fn custom_sort(nums: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    let freq_map = frequency_map(nums);
    let pos_map = position_map(nums);

    nums.sort_unstable_by(|a, b| pos_map.get(b).unwrap().cmp(pos_map.get(a).unwrap()));
    nums.dedup();

    nums.sort_by(|a, b| freq_map.get(b).unwrap().cmp(freq_map.get(a).unwrap()));
}
```

Example:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let mut history = vec![3, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 3];
    custom_sort(&mut history);

    println!("[{}]", history.iter().format(", "));
}
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 5, 2, 6]
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ee153e3df9daf29de13b10095ace7fe8))